# Arranging the list based on the count bubble value

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a collapsible list and list view attached to each collapsible set.

And in each collapsible set I am displaying the value of the number of list elements attached to each collapsible set.

I am creating the collapsible set dynamically as

```html
div = '<div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false" data-iconpos="right" data-collapsible="true" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-r" data-expanded-icon="arrow-d"><h3>' + row['name'] + '<span class="ui-li-count ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-corner-all" data-iconpos="right">' + count + '</span></h3></div>';
```

Now based on my count value I need to align my collapsible set.

Eg: If I have collapsible set with 3 elements

say , class A  1 ,class B  2 , class  C 4 , class D 3

then my collapsible set should look like

class C  4
class D  3
class B  2
Class A  1

How can I do it?

Thanks:)

Comment: can you post the fiddle with your real code?

Comment: is the count coming from a sqlite database ?

Comment: @Malek yea.. count is coming from sqlite database

Comment: @Stiger sorry man i tried to use jsfiddle.. but i was not able to add my code der